# Exact syntax for multiple headers in Play! 2.0 WS request?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Trying to add multiple headers to a Scala Play! WS Request:

```
WS
.url(requestUri)
.withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Oauth %s" format(cred.authorizedToken)),
    "Content-Type" -> "application/json")
.post(httpBody.get)
```

However it is currently failing. What's the proper syntax? I've tried multiple approaches but the compiler complains about java strings. Thanks!

Comment: I havn't tried but your approche seems correct with the source code `def withHeaders(hdrs: (String, String)*)`. This syntax is also documented here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaResults

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what is going on. The thread was executing without headers and now it seems to timeout. I'll keep experimenting around thx

Comment: If it's resolved, i will post a real answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems valid according to the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaResults)

```
Ok("Hello World!").withHeaders(
  CACHE_CONTROL -> "max-age=3600", 
  ETAG -> "xx"
)
```

And the method definition validate your code too :

```
def withHeaders(hdrs: (String, String)*)
// Parameters are infinite couples of String
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's definitely different from the ScalaWS doc example since it has more than one header. Cheers